# Merge in excel with phpSpreadSheet

Tags: php, excel, merge, phpspreadsheet

I want to merge 2 or more excel **with PhpSpreadsheet**. I'm trying to keep the styles for each sheet, this is my code:

```
<?php

    require 'vendor/autoload.php';


    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

    $inputFileType = 'Xlsx';
    $inputFileNames = [
        'a.xlsx',
        'b.xlsx',
        'c.xlsx'
    ];
    $sheetnames = [
        'Worksheet',
        'Worksheet1',
        'Worksheet2'
        ];
    $reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $reader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetnames);
    $inputFileName = array_shift($inputFileNames);
    $spreadsheetMain = $reader->load($inputFileName);
    $spreadsheetMain->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('page0');
    $contador = 1;
    foreach ($inputFileNames as $book => $inputFileName) {
        echo ('$inputFileName: ' . $inputFileName) . '</br>';
        $spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);
        $clonedWorksheet = clone $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setTitle($inputFileName[0]);
        $clonedWorksheet->setTitle('page' . $contador);
        $spreadsheetMain->addSheet($clonedWorksheet);
        $contador++;
    }
    $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheetMain);
    $writer->save('prueba1.xlsx');
```

to do what I want, I need to change this
`$spreadsheetMain->addSheet($clonedWorksheet);`

for that `$spreadsheetMain->addExternalSheet($clonedWorksheet);`

But when I execute that code I get the error: 'Sheet does not exist'

I tought it's not still implemented, but is here in the documentation page: https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/worksheets/#copying-worksheets

Here you can download my excels and code for try if you want:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qkI8jdYDuA6e5CW6z3k0r_7j1pTvW_6D

Comment: You must not change title of cloned sheet, doing so generates the error. Instead rename existing sheet's name in main workbook

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `addExternalSheet` was that I needed to name both sheets (the original that I load and the cloned Sheet) with the same name. (All files are here : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qkI8jdYDuA6e5CW6z3k0r_7j1pTvW_6D, mergeSolved is the correct file) This is the code with the solution:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$inputFileType = 'Xlsx';
$inputFileNames = [
    'a.xlsx',
    'b.xlsx',
    'c.xlsx'
];
$sheetnames = [
    'Worksheet',
    'Worksheet1',
    'Worksheet2'
];
$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$reader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetnames);
$inputFileName = array_shift($inputFileNames);
$spreadsheetMain = $reader->load($inputFileName);
$spreadsheetMain->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('page0');
$contador = 1;
foreach ($inputFileNames as $book => $inputFileName) {
    echo ('$inputFileName: ' . $inputFileName) . '</br>';
    $spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);
    $clonedWorksheet = clone $spreadsheet->getSheetByName('Worksheet'.$contador);
    $clonedWorksheet->setTitle('Worksheet'.$contador);
    $spreadsheetMain->addExternalSheet($clonedWorksheet);
    $contador++;
}
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheetMain);
$writer->save('prueba1.xlsx');`
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$lists = [
    'flie_01.xlsx',
    'flie_02.xlsx'
];

$outfile='/tmp/merge.xlsx';

$merge_spreadsheet = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();        
$merge_spreadsheet->getProperties()->setCreator("act");


foreach($lists as $file){

if(!file_exists($file)){
    continue;
}            

$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader("Xlsx");
$reader-&gt;setReadDataOnly(true);
$spreadsheet = $reader-&gt;load($file);

foreach($spreadsheet-&gt;getSheetNames() as $sheet_name ){
    $clonedWorksheet = clone $spreadsheet-&gt;getSheetByName($sheet_name);
    $clonedWorksheet-&gt;setTitle($sheet_name);
    $merge_spreadsheet-&gt;addSheet($clonedWorksheet);                
}


}

$merge_spreadsheet->removeSheetByIndex(0);  

$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet,'Xlsx');
$writer->save($outfile);
```